# System.InvalidCastException in AxInterop.AXVLC.dll ExceptionSystem.InvalidCastException VLC C#

Tags: c#, vlc, com-interop

can any one help me to solve this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in AxInterop.AXVLC.dll ExceptionSystem.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at AXVLC.IVLCControl2.get_playlist() at AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2.get_playlist()

I want to play media in my VLC plugin, i'm getting my expected result when i'm using OpenFileDialog but i want to open media through my program.

here is my code

```
private void playVideo(string filePath)
{
object filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
Console.WriteLine("FilePath: "+filePath);
Console.WriteLine("FileName: "+ filename);
try
{
vlcPlayer.playlist.add(filePath, filename, null);
//on above line im getting this exception
vlcPlayer.playlist.play();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("Exception" + ex);
}
}
```

Comment: where is the exception occurring?

Comment: vlcPlayer.playlist.add(filePath, filename, null);

on this line i'm getting exception

Comment: what are the parameters expecting? also, why is your `filename` an `object`

Comment: i just referred some videos in which i saw these people are passing three parameters in this method


this is my filepath as first parameter for 
uri : C:\Users\partic\source\repos\SerialPlay\SerialPlay\bin\Debug\videos\A.mp4

& second one is filename : A.mp4

Comment: when i checked add() in that datatype of second parameter is object but, after removing this last two parameters because it's optional still i'm getting same exception because of first parameter

Comment: try to use the folder path instead of the filepath. like `C:\Users\partic\source\repos\SerialPlay\SerialPlay\bin\Debug\videos\` without the `A.mp4` as the first parameter

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: Sorry bro still i'm getting same exception

Comment: Dont use the AXVLC Plugin. It's unmaintained. Use the official VLC C# bindings https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp and recent libvlc from nuget